# Null pointer when setting text/background on android app

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, textview, android-background

For some reason, I am getting a Null pointer exception when I run my app. It works fine until it hits my "ExamActivity" activity. The code i just added is supposed to change the background(according to a vaiable called "gender) and text (according to a variable called "stepnumber") that I pull from SharedPreferences.

I have searched the internet and I cannot seem to find where my code is going wrong! Here is the ExamActivity.java file:

```
public class ExamActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{
public void goToNext(View view)
{
    //set up shared preferences.
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor; 
    prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();  

    //get the current stepnumber
    int stepnumber = myPrefs.getInt("stepnumber", 1);

    //increment the step number by 1
    stepnumber= stepnumber+1;

    //set the value in shared preferences to the new stepnumber.
    prefsEditor.putInt("stepnumber", stepnumber );

    //commit the preferences
     prefsEditor.commit();

    //get whether to move to a camera or a stethoscope view. 
    Boolean camera =myPrefs.getBoolean("camera", true);

    if(camera)
    {
        //go to the new activity.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CameraActivity.class );
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        //go to the new activity.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, StethActivity.class );
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}

public void goBack(View view)
{
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor; 
    prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();

    //get the step number
    int StepNumber= myPrefs.getInt("stepnumber", 1);

    //if we are on the first step
    if(StepNumber==1)
    {
        //then go back to the exam start activity!
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExamStartActivity.class );
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        //otherwise, decrease the step number!
        StepNumber=StepNumber-1;

        //change the value stored in the shared preferences
        prefsEditor.putInt("stepnumber", StepNumber);

        //commit the defaults
         prefsEditor.commit();

        //go to the new activity.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExamActivity.class );
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}


public void SetVariables( Boolean cam , String title , String filename , String audiofile)
{
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor; 
    prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();  

    //set the top label for the step.
     TextView t =new TextView(this); 
     t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewExam); 
     t.setText(title);

    //set whether its a camera or stethoscope test.
     prefsEditor.putBoolean("camera", cam); 

    //set the name of the file the result will be saved to
    prefsEditor.putString("outputfilename", filename);

    //set the audio file
    prefsEditor.putString("soundfile", audiofile);

    //commit the defaults
     prefsEditor.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exam);

    if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
             //////////////////BEGIN CUSTOM IMPLEMENTATION////////////////////////////////////////////////
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

    //get the selected gender
    boolean gender =preferences.getBoolean("gender", false);
    //get the step number.
    int StepNumber= preferences.getInt("stepnumber", 1);

    //if it is female
    if(gender)
    {
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutid);
         rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.womanbasefront2);

    }

    //check which step in the exam we are on.
    if(StepNumber == 1)
    {
        SetVariables(true,"General Head To Toe Pan", "GeneralExam.mov","generalexamaudio");
    }
    else if(StepNumber==2)
    {
        SetVariables(true, "Examine Oral Mucosa" ,"OralMucosa.mov","oralmucosaexamaudio");
    }
    else if(StepNumber ==3 )
    {
        SetVariables(false ,"Auscultate Aortic Site At Right Upper Sternal Border" ,"AorticCardiacAuscultation.wav","aorticcardiacauscultationexamaudio");
    }
    else if(StepNumber==4)
    {
        SetVariables(false ,"Auscultate Pulmonic Site at Left Upper Sternal Border" ,"PulmonicCardiacAuscultation.wav","pulmoniccardiacauscultationexamaudio");
    }
    else if(StepNumber==5)
    {
        SetVariables(false,"Auscultate Tricuspid Site At Left Lower Sternal Border" ,"TricuspidCardiacAuscultation.wav","tricuspidcardiacauscultationexamaudio");
    }
    else if(StepNumber==6)
    {
        SetVariables(false, "Auscultate Mitral Site at the Apex" ,"MitralCardiacAuscultation.wav","mitralmardiacauscultationexamaudio");
    }
    else if(StepNumber==7)
    {
        //flip step
        SetVariables(false,"Austcultate Pulmonary Left Apex with deep breaths" ,"LeftApexPulmonaryAuscultation.wav","leftapexpulmonaryauscultationexamaudio");

    }
    else if(StepNumber==8)
    {
        //flip step
        SetVariables(false,"Auscultate Pulmonary Right Apex with deep breaths","RightApexPulmonaryAuscultation.wav","rightapexpulmonaryauscultationexamaudio");

    }
    else if(StepNumber==9)
    {
        //flip step
        SetVariables(false, "Auscultate Pulmonary Left Middle with deep breaths" ,"LeftMiddlePulmonaryAuscultation.wav" ,"leftmiddlepulmonaryauscultationexamaudio");
    }
    else if(StepNumber==10)
    {
        //flip step
        SetVariables(false, "Auscultate Pulmonary Right Middle with deep breaths" ,"RightMiddlePulmonaryAuscultation.wav" ,"rightmiddlepulmonaryauscultationexamaudio");
    }
    else if(StepNumber==11)
    {
        //flip step
        SetVariables(false, "Auscultate Pulmonary Left Base with deep breaths" ,"LeftBasePulmonaryAuscultation.wav" ,"leftbasepulmonaryauscultationexamaudio");
    }
    else if(StepNumber==12)

    {
        //flip step
        SetVariables(false ,"Auscultate Pulmonary Right Base with deep breaths" ,"RightBasePulmonaryAuscultation.wav" ,"rightbasepulmonaryauscultationexamaudio");
    }
    else if(StepNumber==13)
    {
        //NOT SURE IF CORRECT AUDIO FILE!!!!
        SetVariables(true ,"Record Right Jugular Vein from Anterior Mid-Clavicle" ,"RightAnteriorInternalJugularExam.mov", "rightanteriorinternaljugularexamaudio");
    }
    else if(StepNumber==14)
    {
        SetVariables(true ,"Record Right Jugular Vein from Lateral Shoulder" ,"RightLateralInternalJugularExam.mov","rightlateralinternaljugularexamaudio");
    }
    else if(StepNumber==15)
    {
        SetVariables(true ,"Record Left Jugular Vein from Anterior Mid-Clavicle" ,"LeftAnteriorInternalJugularExam.mov","leftanteriorinternaljugularexamaudio");
    }
    else if(StepNumber==16)
    {
        SetVariables(true ,"Record Left Jugular Vein from Lateral Shoulder" ,"LeftLateralInternalJugularExam.mov","leftlateralinternaljugularexamaudio");
    }
    else if(StepNumber==17)
    {
       SetVariables(true,"Record right lower extremity from knee after firmly pressing with finger","RightSuperiorLowerExtremityExam.mov","rightsuperiorlowerextremityexamaudio");
    }
    else if(StepNumber==18)
    {
        SetVariables(true, "Record right shin 2 feet Anterior to Shin after pressing firmly with finger","RightAnteriorLowerExtremityExam.mov","rightanteriorlowerextremityexamaudio");
    }
    else if(StepNumber==19)
    {
        SetVariables(true ,"Record Left Lower Knee Extremity from Knee after pressing lightly with finger","LeftSuperiorLowerExtremityExam.mov","leftsuperiorlowerextremityexamaudio");
    }
    else if(StepNumber==20)
    {
        SetVariables(true, "Record Left shin 2 feet Anterior to Shin after firmly pressing with finger","LeftAnteriorLowerExtremityExam.mov","leftanteriorlowerextremityexamaudio");
    }
    else
    {


    }
        ////////////////////////END CUSTOM IMPLEMENTATION///////////////////////
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.exam, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment 
{

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exam, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Here is the xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutid"
    android:background="@drawable/manimagebasefront2" 
    tools:context="com.telehealthcaresolutions.virtualphysical.ExamActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewExam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewExam"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:onClick="goBack"
        android:text="Back"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textViewExam"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:onClick="goToNext"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Log Cat Output:

```
    05-29 11:23:28.406: E/ActivityThread(18288): Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.telehealthcaresolutions.virtualphysical/com.telehealthcaresolutions.virtualphysical.LoginPageActivity}
05-29 11:23:28.406: E/ActivityThread(18288): java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.telehealthcaresolutions.virtualphysical/com.telehealthcaresolutions.virtualphysical.LoginPageActivity}
05-29 11:23:28.406: E/ActivityThread(18288):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3333)
05-29 11:23:28.406: E/ActivityThread(18288):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3420)
05-29 11:23:28.406: E/ActivityThread(18288):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:161)
05-29 11:23:28.406: E/ActivityThread(18288):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
05-29 11:23:28.406: E/ActivityThread(18288):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-29 11:23:28.406: E/ActivityThread(18288):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
05-29 11:23:28.406: E/ActivityThread(18288):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
05-29 11:23:28.406: E/ActivityThread(18288):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 11:23:28.406: E/ActivityThread(18288):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-29 11:23:28.406: E/ActivityThread(18288):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
05-29 11:23:28.406: E/ActivityThread(18288):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
05-29 11:23:28.406: E/ActivityThread(18288):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 11:23:31.188: W/ApplicationPackageManager(18288): getCSCPackageItemText()
05-29 11:23:33.230: W/ApplicationPackageManager(18288): getCSCPackageItemText()
05-29 11:23:33.260: D/AndroidRuntime(18288): Shutting down VM
05-29 11:23:33.260: W/dalvikvm(18288): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4172ada0)
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288): Process: com.telehealthcaresolutions.virtualphysical, PID: 18288
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.telehealthcaresolutions.virtualphysical/com.telehealthcaresolutions.virtualphysical.ExamActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at com.telehealthcaresolutions.virtualphysical.ExamActivity.SetVariables(ExamActivity.java:108)
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at com.telehealthcaresolutions.virtualphysical.ExamActivity.onCreate(ExamActivity.java:152)
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
05-29 11:23:33.260: E/AndroidRuntime(18288):    ... 11 more
```

EDIT: I moved everything i had from the onCreate() to the OnViewCreate(). But it said that I "cannot make a static reference to the nonstatic method SetVariables"
So i created an activity instance and tried to call the SetVariables Function from OnviewCreate. I don't know how to set a newly created activity to the current activity i am working on. The app still crashes on the "ExamActivity" activity. Here are the changes:

```
//i know this line is not correct... i don't know how to set it equal to my current activity?
            ExamActivity myactivity= new ExamActivity();


        SharedPreferences preferences = myactivity.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

        //get the selected gender
        boolean gender =preferences.getBoolean("gender", false);
        //get the step number.
        int StepNumber= preferences.getInt("stepnumber", 1);

        //if it is female
        if(gender)
        {
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) myactivity.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutid);
            rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.womanbasefront2);

        }

        //check which step in the exam we are on.
        if(StepNumber == 1)
        {
            myactivity.SetVariables(true,"General Head To Toe Pan", "GeneralExam.mov","generalexamaudio");
        }
        else if(StepNumber==2)
        {
            myactivity.SetVariables(true, "Examine Oral Mucosa" ,"OralMucosa.mov","oralmucosaexamaudio");
        } .......
```

This gets rid of the error messages about needing the function to be static, but the app still crashes!! I changed the SetVariables function to a static function, but that only created more errors. New Log Cat Errors:

```
05-29 14:40:33.196: E/ActivityThread(8047): Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.telehealthcaresolutions.virtualphysical/com.telehealthcaresolutions.virtualphysical.MainMenuActivity}
05-29 14:40:33.196: E/ActivityThread(8047): java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.telehealthcaresolutions.virtualphysical/com.telehealthcaresolutions.virtualphysical.MainMenuActivity}
05-29 14:40:33.196: E/ActivityThread(8047):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3333)
05-29 14:40:33.196: E/ActivityThread(8047):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3420)
05-29 14:40:33.196: E/ActivityThread(8047):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:161)
05-29 14:40:33.196: E/ActivityThread(8047):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
05-29 14:40:33.196: E/ActivityThread(8047):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-29 14:40:33.196: E/ActivityThread(8047):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
05-29 14:40:33.196: E/ActivityThread(8047):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
05-29 14:40:33.196: E/ActivityThread(8047):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 14:40:33.196: E/ActivityThread(8047):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-29 14:40:33.196: E/ActivityThread(8047):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
05-29 14:40:33.196: E/ActivityThread(8047):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
05-29 14:40:33.196: E/ActivityThread(8047):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 14:40:33.656: W/ApplicationPackageManager(8047): getCSCPackageItemText()
05-29 14:40:33.686: D/AndroidRuntime(8047): Shutting down VM
05-29 14:40:33.686: W/dalvikvm(8047): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4172ada0)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047): Process: com.telehealthcaresolutions.virtualphysical, PID: 8047
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.telehealthcaresolutions.virtualphysical/com.telehealthcaresolutions.virtualphysical.ExamActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:185)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at com.telehealthcaresolutions.virtualphysical.ExamActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(ExamActivity.java:180)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1189)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5436)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
05-29 14:40:33.696: E/AndroidRuntime(8047):     ... 11 more
```

I am just so confused as to why this is not working. It is saying it has some problem with getting the values from getSharedPreferences . . . but i don't know how to fix it!

any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Write a [sscce](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: The logcat points to line 108 of SetVariables and 152 in onCreate.Which are these lines?

Comment: Please provide line numbers.

Comment: t.setText(title); --- is line 108 and
SetVariables(true,"General Head To Toe Pan", "GeneralExam.mov","generalexamaudio");  --is line 152

Comment: You need to call `findViewById()` on the inflated view, not on the activity (which causes the static/non-static reference problem as well as not solving the original problem - the views are not in the activity view hierarchy). For example, `rootView.findViewById(R.id.whatever)`.

Comment: I still don't really understand . What is the "whatever" i am supposed to be calling the findViewById? Do i create a new view in my xml file?(that seems to be what the other code example on the duplicate does). I need to be able to call my function SetVariables in the OnViewCreate somehow, but it complains that it is a nonstatic function. If i change SetVariabes to static, then errors appear in the SetVariables function complaining that I cannot have static references to nonstatic methods. Do i need to make changes to SetVariables? What do i need to do to be able to call it from onCreateView?